# Como organizar o retorno de dados em um List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Tenho um wcf que me retorna algumas informações, gostaria de trazer elas organizadas, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Gostaria de retornar dados assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento esta assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo assim:

```html
 public List<V_PRODUTOS> GetProdutos(string credencial)
        {
            if (credencial != ChaveCredencial)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro: Usuário não autorizado");
            }

            try{

                using(SERRESTEEntities entites = new SERRESTEEntities())
                return entites.V_PRODUTOS.ToList();

            } 
            catch
            {
                throw new FaultException("Something went wrong");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Você está usando o Json.net?

Answer (score 1):

itasousa, eu particularmente desaconselho que você formate o retorno, isto apenas vai deixar o tamanho do seu response maior e não vai lhe trazer nenhum beneficio.

Em todo caso, você pode alterar a forma como o WCF serializa os dados, desta forma você pode usar Json.NET ao invés da classe padrão.

para tal você vai precisar implementar estas duas interfaces:

```
public interface IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
    void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters);
    Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result);
}

public interface IClientMessageFormatter
{
    Message SerializeRequest(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters);
    object DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters);
}
```

E por fim vai precisar incluir os Formatter em algum Behavior e associar este Behavior a algum EndPoint.

Veja que este processo não é tão simples, eu até vejo alguns benefícios  em substituir a classe de serialização padrão pelo Json.NET, porem se o intuito for apenas identar o JSON, peço que considere a seguinte alternativa:

Instale algum dos seguintes plugins no seu navegador de preferencia:

- [Chrome - JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
- [Opera - JsonViewer](https://addons.opera.com/pt/extensions/details/jsonviewer/?display=en)
- [Mozilla - JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/jsonview/)

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas talvez se você colocar no global.asax as linhas a seguir resolva.

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: Não tem global.asax e um webservice WCF Rest

Comment: Desculpa, confundi com o WebApi